# How to pass a observable property (of knockout) to view

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, razor-2

I am having a dropdown binded with a ko.observableArray([]). Here I am capturing selected value in vm.selectedUser which is a ko.observable(). I want to assign this value to a hidden field in view on onchange event  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserName, new {id="hiddenUser" })

$("#hiddenUser").val(vm.selectedUser);

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: you can subscribe to change and do that

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to change to do that

```
vm.selectedUser.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    $("#hiddenUser").val(newValue));
});
```

or just bind the hidden field to your observable, that should work too

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserName, new {id="hiddenUser",data_bind = "value: selectedUser" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something [**like this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/qU2Za/) (I have created my fiddle in my own coding style, may or may not match yours, Apologies! )

Assuming,

```
var Users = ko.observableArray([]);//Your User List
var SelectedUser=ko.observable();//Your Dropdown selected Item, can be ID or Name.
```

You can write/define a function for change event  of dropdown:-

```
function selectionChanged(data){
console.log(SelectedUser());
    $('#hiddenUser').val(SelectedUser());//Displaying it in Textbox
            $('#hiddenUser2').val(SelectedUser());//Saving it in hidden field

};
```

Where my HTML markup would be as follows:-

```
<select data-bind="options: Users, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',value: SelectedUser,event: { change: selectionChanged }"></select>

<input type="text" id="hiddenUser"></input>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenUser2"></input>
```

You can also look into [Fiddle Example by RP Niemeyer](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LBz6d/)

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery and a subscribe, just bind the hidden input directly to the selectedUser observable:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserName, new {id="hiddenUser", data_bind="value: selectedUser" })
```

Note that it is "data_bind" instead of "data-bind".  In Razor, the dash is an invalid name character, but it will automatically convert the underscore to a dash.

[Don't mean for this to be an advertisement, but this is one of the items I demonstrate in my video on using Knockout and MVC together at WintellectNOW dot com if you are interested.]